# MODx Revolution - Timeout happens every minutes causing logout

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

Setup:
MODX Revolution 2.2.4-pl (traditional)
Hosting: HostGator Shared Linux server

Problem:
After I have logged into the CMS, when I go to make changes to a resource, snippet or any other facet of the site, regardless of how long it took (10 seconds to 10 minutes) I get a screen saying session timed out and have to login again.

I've got 50 installations of MODx on my Dedicated IIS7 Rackspace box that have never given me a problem.

I only have one Warning which I've never seen before in the Manager Panel:
Configuration warning: register_globals is set to ON in your php.ini configuration file

Any thoughts on why it would be kicking me out almost every time I go to make a change?
Thanks in Advance for any help.

Comment: And this is browser independent. It happens in all browsers, IE, FF, Chrome...

Comment: Someone close this question. The Register Globals var in php.ini was the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently solved this issue by setting my servers' Session Save Path. Take a look at your php5.ini configuration file (create it if it doesn't exist). create a folder on your server (ex. php_sessions) and give it write access (CHMOD 777).

Then add the following:  `session.save_path = "/path/to/your/root/html/php_sessions"`

This should work right away, but depending on your host (ex. godaddy) you might have to restart your web services.

Really hope this works for you as well m8! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks much. After thinking I had the problem fixed, it resurfaced. So I'll be trying this.